# Why this delegate function doesn't work in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I executed the methods in the following order.
In that case, something unexpected happened.
What could be the cause?

Following Actions

1. Deploy A
2. Deploy B with the address "a".
3. delegate function of B from address X to address Y
4. checkDelegates from X to Y. (But I cannot get the result of true)

My returned result

```
console.log:
 delegater == msg.sender
 delegater== 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4
 delegatee == 0xd8b934580fcE35a11B58C6D73aDeE468a2833fa8
 Before: delegates[delegater] == delegatee ==  false
 After: delegates[delegater] == delegatee ==  true
 
call to B.checkDelegates
CALL
[call]from: 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4to: B.checkDelegates(address,address)data: 0x564...33fa8
console.log:
 msg.sender== 0xd8b934580fcE35a11B58C6D73aDeE468a2833fa8
 delegater== 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4
 delegatee== 0xd8b934580fcE35a11B58C6D73aDeE468a2833fa8
 delegates[delegater] == delegatee ==  false
```

### Code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;
import "hardhat/console.sol";
contract A {
    mapping (address => address) public delegates;
    function delegate(address delegatee) public returns (bool){
        require (delegatee != address(0), "can't delegate to 0 address");
        address delegater = msg.sender;

        console.log("delegater == msg.sender");
        console.log("delegater==", msg.sender);
        console.log("delegatee ==",delegatee);
        console.log("Before: delegates[delegater] == delegatee == ", delegates[delegater] == delegatee);
        delegates[msg.sender] = delegatee;
        console.log("After: delegates[delegater] == delegatee == ", delegates[delegater] == delegatee);
        return true;
    }

    function checkDelegates(address delegater, address delegatee) public view returns(bool){
        console.log("msg.sender==",msg.sender);
        console.log("delegater==", delegater);        
        console.log("delegatee==", delegatee);        
        console.log("delegates[delegater] == delegatee == ", delegates[delegater] == delegatee);
        return delegates[delegater] == delegatee;
    }
}

contract B {
    A a;
    constructor(A _a) public {
        a = _a;
    }
    function delegate(address addr) public {
        (bool success,)
        = address(a).delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("delegate(address)", addr));
        require(success, "Failed");
    }
    function checkDelegates(address _delegater,address _delegatee) public view returns(bool success){
        success = a.checkDelegates(_delegater,_delegatee);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `delegates` are written in the state of contract `B`, but the function `checkDelegates` looks at the state of `A`.

Basically at the third step, when you call function `delegate`, contract B delegatecalls A, meaning that the state is written in B.

At the fourth step, `checkDelegates` makes a simple call (*not* delegatecall) to A, meaning that the state of A is read.

You should be consistent, for example using only delegatecalls in contract B.